# Firebase Database not syncing properly when changed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Database Accessing** [image: Firebase Database]

**Problem**: When changing data in Firebase Database or take an instance when I added 'disease: "Food Poisoning"' to each node, it stops working. My code is properly synced for accessing the database with last key as 'disease'. So, when adding 'disease' as leaf node to every other node and running the code again, it shows "App has stopped".

**SymptomActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.security.SecurityPermission;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class SymptomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase, spinnerDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
Button button;
TextView textView,symptom1,symptom2,symptom3;
Spinner spinner,spinner2,spinner3;
String textSymptom1,textSymptom2,textSymptom3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_symptom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    symptom1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.symptom1);
    symptom2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.symptom2);
    symptom3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.symptom3);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    // Write a message to the database
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // store app title to 'app_title' node
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").setValue("microDoctor");
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomList");
    spinnerDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomView");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.child("Headache").child("Some Value").setValue("Head");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.setValue("Headache");


    spinnerData();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            textSymptom1 = spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            textSymptom2 = spinner2.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            textSymptom3 = spinner3.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            readDataListener();
        }
    });
}

private void readDataListener() {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(textSymptom1).child(textSymptom2).child(textSymptom3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Symptom symptom = dataSnapshot.getValue(Symptom.class);

            // Check for null
            if (symptom == null) {
                Log.e("Data", "Symptom data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e("Symptom Data", "User data is changed!"+symptom.getDisease());

            // Display newly updated name and email
            textView.setText(symptom.disease+"\n"+dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
private void spinnerData() {
    spinnerDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e("Spinner Data", "Spinner data is changed!");

            //DataSnapshot data = dataSnapshot;
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> temp = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
//                list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
//                showDataInSpinner(list);
            for (DataSnapshot lists : temp){
                Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+lists.getValue().toString());
                list.add(lists.getValue().toString());
                textView.setText(lists.getValue().toString());
            }
            showDataInSpinner(list);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
public void showDataInSpinner(ArrayList<String> data) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data
    ); //Create the Adapter to set the data
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Set the layout resource to create the drop down views.
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); //Set the data to your spinner
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**Logcat**

```
11-10 23:28:57.985 27635-27640/com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=51KB, data=61KB
11-10 23:28:57.985 27635-27640/com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor I/art: After code cache collection, code=51KB, data=61KB
11-10 23:28:57.985 27635-27640/com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
11-10 23:29:06.787 27635-27635/com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-10 23:29:06.788 27635-27635/com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor, PID: 27635
                                                                                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor.Symptom
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor.SymptomActivity$6.onDataChange(SymptomActivity.java:127)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeex.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegs.zzbwg(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegy.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fetch `disease` values which is `String` so to fetch it, use

```
String symptom = dataSnapshot.child("disease").getValue(String.class);
```

or

```
String symptom = (String)dataSnapshot.child("disease").getValue();
// the return type is an object 
// but internally the appropriate native type will be returned
```

Comment: Output: {disease=Food Poisoning}.
Expected Output: Food Poisoning.

Comment: @NishantSikri you need to go one step deep as `String symptom = dataSnapshot.child("disease").getValue(String.class);`

Comment: Moreover, when when I press Button, output first comes as "Food Poisoning" but it immediately changes to "{disease=Food Poisoning}".

Comment: umm.. Solved with your comment.